# How to Report Cyclic Flagging?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging, exact-duplicates

[This question](https://superuser.com/q/45697/463743) is flagged as a duplicate of this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/755298/how-to-delete-a-file-with-a-path-too-long-to-be-deleted). However, that 2nd question is also flagged as a duplicate of the first.

How do I bring this to the proper individuals' attention?

Comment: Use a free-text moderator attention flag to report this condition.

Comment: What's a "free-text moderation attention flag"? In fact, how do I even do a "moderator attention flag" period?

Comment: @SarahofGaia Under each answer or question should be a "flag" button, if you click that and select "in need of moderator intervention" it will give you a text box where you can tell us what's wrong.

Comment: Oh, yes of course I remember that! Sorry. X3

Comment: Also, would your username be, by any chance, a reference to a certain anime? :3

Comment: Also, is there any such thing as a moderator attention flag that is *not* free-text?

Comment: @SarahofGaia I found out about the similarity with an anime character some years after I started using the name and by then it was too late. It was not intentional and you're the first person (seemingly) to have noticed it... :)

Comment: As to non-freetext flags, most flags you can raise will be able to be seen by a moderator but who handles it or whether it gets through the review queue before a moderator sees it is up to chance. If you *need* a moderator then a custom flag is the way to go but it could be seen and handled by *any* moderator.

Comment: I see. Okay, thank you.

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing the system could automatically notice and prevent, but I'm guessing the cost-benefit of fixing it isn't worth the effort. Ah well.

Comment: @ParthianShot: I don't think it happens often enough for the devs to care enough to fix it, sadly. :/

Comment: A better title might be "How can I report cyclic duplicates?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Someone went and edited the duplicate close banner, which normally shouldn't be able to happen. The problem in this case is that the question was closed before the current system was put in place and the the banner was handled differently back then.

I have edited it and re-closed it to fix the duplicate banner.

The way to go about reporting this is either via a custom moderator flag or by posting on meta as you have done.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. :) And wonderful; I'm glad I did the right action!